# Is "odom" frame in this wiki mean a world coordinate?

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, frame

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm studying navigation stack.
I usually refer to navigation stack's wiki and now I'm reading this page (http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom).

In this page, there is some coordinate frame which is called "odom".
I guess that this frame is equal to a world coordinate("/map" frame in rvis).

Is my guess correct?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37029/is-%22odom%22-frame-in-this-wiki-mean-a-world-coordinate?/) by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 721 on 2012-06-21

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[REP 105](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html#coordinate-frames) defines the various frames.

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2012-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here in this example robot-base location (via transform publish from /odom to /base_link) is computed w.r.t. /odom frame. The /odom frame is fixed frame so you can assume it is acting as world frame. But a world frame could be completely different from /odom or /map.

---

Originally posted by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) with karma: 660 on 2012-06-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- `/odom` is the standardized name of the world frame of the **odometry** component (robot movement is continuous but the frame drifts)
- `/map` is the standardized name of the world frame of the **localization** component  (do not drift, but movement is not continuous)

You may have none, one or both depending on what components are running. `robot_pose_ekf` is the traditional package for providing odometry based on the integration of several sensors output (wheel odometry, IMU and a third optional source such as visual odometry). You also have `viso2_ros` which is dedicated to visual odometry.

An example of localization without odometry would be, for instance, a motion capture system (`motion_analysis_mocap`) or the ground truth of a robotics simulator (`gazebo`).

You can see the interest of tf here as any of these setup can be used and it is totally transparent for the navigation stack as long as the frames are defined.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2012-06-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12